# Bootstrap thumbnail caption hover-effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-hover

Html code:

```
 <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">            
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>Banking & Finance</h4>
                        <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                        <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom"></a>
                        <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Learn More">Learn More..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/1/" alt="...">
                </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">            
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>Education</h4>
                        <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                        <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom"></a>
                        <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Learn More..">Learn More..</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/2/" alt="...">
                </div>
          </div>


      </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250);

    $('.thumbnail').hover(

        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        }
    ); 
});
```

css:

```
thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(30, 165, 158, 0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
```

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/salmanamaan24/4u6tL/3/

In the below code(done using bootstrap) i have an image and when hover on it, i had given some effect with green color. so what i want is reverse of it..when ever i run the file by default it must show the hover effect
and when i place my cursor on it must show the image...Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: change slideUp to slideDown and slideDown to slideUp in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4u6tL/1/)

Is this what you're looking for?

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250);


         $('.thumbnail').hover(

        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); 
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); 
        }
    );


});
```